# Spring Security : convert XML to Annotation

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to use the OpenID Connect client with Spring Java annotation.

Unfortunately, the sample [Mitre ID Connect client](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/simple-web-app) is based on XML.

I managed to load XML by **@ImportResource("classpath:servlet-context.xml")**
but it would be much better to have pure Java annotation based solution.

I could not translate the following XML stuff into Spring Annotation:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
        disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
        pattern="/**">
        <security:custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter" />
        <security:logout />
</security:http>



<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="openIdConnectAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>


<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="http://localhost:10239/test" />
</bean>



<util:set id="namedAdmins" value-type="org.mitre.openid.connect.client.SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority">
    <bean class="org.mitre.openid.connect.client.SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority">
            <constructor-arg name="subject" value="XXX" />
            <constructor-arg name="issuer" value="http://localhost:10239/test" />
        </bean>
    </util:set>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bean xml tag is similar to the @bean annotation. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

The util:set tag is similar to a method that returns a set of type org.mitre.openid.connect.client.SubjectIssuerGrantedAuthority. However this method has the @bean annotation as well.

For security related tags you can extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
see https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/